# how to change web.config when upgrading to Windows Azure.2.5

Tags: azure, azure-pack

I'd like to know how to change web.config when upgrading to Windows Azure 2.5. Current `web.config` is like

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.8.0.0" newVersion="1.8.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: What NuGet package do you use? [This one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unofficial.Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime/)?

Comment: No NuGet package is installed for WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, only WindowsAzure.Configuration and WindowsAzure.Storage. The version of ServiceRuntime is 2.5.

Comment: did you try the assembly redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily edit your `bindingRedirect` section like this:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.4.0.0" newVersion="2.5.0.0" />
```